# Create-react-app on mac external drive keeps refreshing page

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, create-react-app, fsevents

I am running a react app created with create-react-app ("react": "^16.13.1", nodejs: 13.12.0) on an external drive connected through USB-C to a MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina).
After `npm start` the app keeps refreshing every ≈ 10 seconds (it's not constant interval) without any change to the files. The page also gets reloaded in the browser.
I prevented Spotlight from indexing this drive (by adding to Privacy) but still the issue persists. Also tried on another MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina). On one of the notebooks there is no antivirus installed.

The same application runs without any reloads from each of the MBPs own internal drives.
I'm not sure what else can trigger the reload on the external drive.

After I start the npm app (disk access led blinks with each app/page reload):

```
USB-C: sudo lsof +D "/Volumes/USB-C"
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
mds       136          root   21r   DIR   1,11    32768      2 /Volumes/USB-C
zsh     81813 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    250 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend
zsh     82998 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768      2 /Volumes/USB-C
node    86986 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    250 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend
node    86987 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    250 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend
node    86988 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    250 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend
node    86988 username  txt    REG   1,11    36204 649396 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend/node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node
sudo    87013          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768      2 /Volumes/USB-C
lsof    87014          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768      2 /Volumes/USB-C
lsof    87015          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768      2 /Volumes/USB-C
```

In normal use (app not running, disk led not blinking, no access)

```
USB-C: sudo lsof +D "/Volumes/USB-C"
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mds       136          root   21r   DIR   1,11    32768    2 /Volumes/USB-C
zsh     81813 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768  250 /Volumes/USB-C/myproject/frontend
zsh     82998 username  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    2 /Volumes/USB-C
sudo    87126          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    2 /Volumes/USB-C
lsof    87127          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    2 /Volumes/USB-C
lsof    87128          root  cwd    DIR   1,11    32768    2 /Volumes/USB-C
```

I used an USB stick also, I get same behaviour just time between refreshes seems to be a bit longer (probably due to slower speed of the drive)

Update: I formatted the drive to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and the issue does not appear anymore. Before both drives I tried were using MS-DOS (FAT) filesystem